# Is there a way to simplify repetitive getters?

Tags: c#, getter-setter, getter

I have a c# class with many variables, all initialized to null. When first accessed, I want to compute their value and return that (storing it to speed up future accesses). To do so, I've written code like

```
private T nullCheck<T>(T value, string how_to_compute) {
    if (value == null) {
        return compute(how_to_compute);
    }
    return value;
}

private string _variable1
public string variable1 {
    get { _variable1 = nullCheck(_variable1, "someData"); return _variable1; }
    set { _variable1 = value; }
}

...
```

With each variable having similar code to `variable1`

Is there some better way to do this? Like a custom annotation that automatically creates these near-identical getters and setters?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to initialize the property? You can use anonymous properties with initial values: `public string variable1 { get; set; } = "someData;"`

Comment: Initializing the property could potentially take a lot of work to do, so I want to offload that until it's necessary (usually most properties are ignored)

Comment: `string how_to_compute .. return compute(how_to_compute);` - this is a bit confusing. How are you computing a value from a string? How are you specifying `T` here?

Comment: I think this is a case of "dead by premature optimization"... unless you are going to create hundreds of thousands of instances of the class the resources consumed by the initialization of a property are negligible. It will consume a lot more resources the check that you will execute each time you access a property.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
public string variable1
{
    get { _variable1 = _variable1 ?? compute("some_data"); return _variable1; }
    set { _variable1 = value; }
}
```